# jQuery: Create an element inside another created element

Tags: jquery

In the following string, I'm trying to add an additional span around the `post.caption` but keep it inside the `<span class="overlay" />`. I've tried prepend and wrap before and after the .html, but can't get it or anything to do it correctly.

`$('<span class="overlay" />').html(post.caption).appendTo(entry);`

Result would look like `<span class="overlay"><span>Caption content</span></span>`

Here's the full snippet if that helps:

```
entry = $('<a />').attr('href', post.permalinkFull)
        $('<img />').attr('src', post.image).appendTo(entry)
        $('<span class="overlay" />').html(post.caption).appendTo(entry);
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `post.caption`?

Comment: Shouldn't be `<span class="overlay"></span>` ?

Comment: @EmCo Not necessarily. `$('<span class="overlay" />')` works fine as well

Comment: @Ryan, when are you adding `entry` to the document?

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvqfm/2/) ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if post.caption is a string, then as I understand it you also want to create the span around it:

```
$('<span>').html(post.caption).appendTo(entry).wrap('<span class="overlay" />');
```

Comment: This one worked! The ordering of everything. Many thanks @mitai and all that chimed in.

Comment: Good luck! Please remember to mark the answer as correct, I need a few more points before I can comment on stuff around here :)

Comment: great, I just got the "comment everywhere" privilege, I'm on my way to the top :P

Answer (score 3):

You can try this with `wrapInner`:

```
$('<span class="overlay" />').html(post.caption)
                             .wrapInner('<span />').appendTo(entry);
```